# Wrong legends when plotting histogram with `hold on`

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, legend

I am plotting histograms on a subplot, where each plot has two histograms as shown in one part of the subplot below:

[image]

**Question:** I would want the hist with variable named `result_uT_per_window` to have red legend, and hist with variable named `uT_top_of_global_window` to have blue legend. I thought what I have in code is supposed to do that, but it doesn't. This is the code:

```
    hold on
    hist(nonzeros(result_uT_per_window(:,window_no)))
    hist(uT_top_of_global_window)
    h = findobj(gca, 'Type','patch');
    set(h(1), 'FaceColor','r', 'EdgeColor','w')
    set(h(2), 'FaceColor','b', 'EdgeColor','w')
    xlabel('Total Velocity (in m/s)')
    ylabel('Frequency')
    legend('From moving window','From global window')
```

Can you notice where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why is the solution to your problem not just `legend('From global window','From moving window')`?

Comment: Note that generally the handle order is such that the last-created handle is `h(1)` if I remember correctly.

Comment: You have swapped the legends. What you have written is what histogram is showing; however, if you look at my code I want it the other way round.

Comment: My main point is: your question is not understandable, because only your know which `hist` command is supposed to correspond to which data and to which legend entry. Provide an artificial test case where we actually *see* what the data in the two histograms is!

Comment: Sorry Jonas for not being clear in my question. My question is that I would want the hist with variable named `result_uT_per_window` to have red legend, and hist with variable named `uT_top_of_global_window` to have blue legend. I thought what I have in code is supposed to do that, but it doesn't. Let me know if I am still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go wrong in assuming that `h(1)` is what was produced by your first `hist` command:

```
data1=normrnd(10,1,10000,1);
data2=normrnd(20,1,10000,1);
figure;
hold on;
hist(data1);
hist(data2);
h = findobj(gca, 'Type','patch');
set(h(1), 'FaceColor','r', 'EdgeColor','w') % color h1 plot red
set(h(2), 'FaceColor','b', 'EdgeColor','w') % color h2 plot blue
```

produces

[image]

showing that data1 (with mean value 10) is plotted in blue, proving that its handle is h(2) even though it was plotted first.

Hence, to solve your problem you could write

```
h = flipud(findobj(gca, 'Type','patch'));
```

to bring the handles in `h` in the order that you expect.