# Legend doesn't show right color in histogram using 'hold on'

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

When I plot multiple histograms while using 'hold on', the color of the legend do not match for the first histogram. See figure below:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
figure(1)
h1 = histogram(y_rating2,50);

hold on

h2 = histogram(y_rating2,50);
l1 = line([rating_1_common_mean rating_1_common_mean],[0 max(h2.Values)],'Color','red','LineWidth',1.5); 

hold on

l2 = line([rating_2_common_mean rating_2_common_mean],[0 max(h2.Values)],'Color','green','LineWidth',1.5);

legend([h1 h2 l1 l2],{'Rating 1','Rating 2','Mean Rating 1','Mean Rating 2'});
```

**Notice:**
I have tried this without any luck:
[Wrong legends when plotting histogram with `hold on`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217777/wrong-legends-when-plotting-histogram-with-hold-on)

Comment: That's because of the transparency effect. All your data in Rating 1 is below Rating 2. If part of the data was higher than Rating 2, you would see the correct color.

Comment: So I should simply swap them?

Comment: Yes, that would solve the issue in your case. Also set `FaceAlpha` to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `FaceAlpha` to 1 and plot rating 1 after rating 2. E.g.

```
h2 = histogram(y_rating2, 50, 'FaceAlpha', 1);
hold on;
h1 = histogram(y_rating1, 50, 'FaceAlpha', 1);
```